# RGB => HSL => hue range name conversion algorithm off by positive 60 degrees

Tags: algorithm, ruby, colors

**Background**
For practice (in ruby) I am implementing some color conversion algorithms. I have attempted to convert pseudocode avilable on [EasyRGB.com](https://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php#text18) to Ruby. The conversion seems to be working fine.

According to [HSL color space theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Basic_principle) the color red is at exactly 0 degrees and the hue range for red accounts for approximately 60 degrees of the color circle from -30 degrees to 30 degress (this depends on how fine one would like to divide the wheel).

[image: HSL Color Wheel]
<sub>(source: [med.sc.edu](http://dba.med.sc.edu/price/irf/Adobe_tg/models/images/hsl_top.JPG))</sub>

For my purposes I'm dividing the wheel in to 6 sections. With the other five hue ranges each accounting for 60 degrees.

**Problem**
When I attempt to use the hue value generated by my conversion function my calculations are off by positive 60 degrees.

**What the result should be according to color theory**

```
def hue_name_from_hue_value(hue_value)
    color_angle = hue_value * 360

    # still can't do grays
    # saturation of 0 = gray
    # lightness of 0 = black
    # lightness of 1 = white
    # there has to be a threshold for when it's considered white or black
    # there has to be a threshold for when it's considered gray or the color in question

    if 30 >= color_angle and color_angle < 90
        return HUE_LIST[:YELLOW]
    elsif 90 >= color_angle and color_angle < 150
        return HUE_LIST[:GREEN]
    elsif 150 >= color_angle and color_angle < 210
        return HUE_LIST[:CYAN]
    elsif 210 >= color_angle and color_angle < 270
        return HUE_LIST[:BLUE]
    elsif 270 >= color_angle and color_angle < 330
        return HUE_LIST[:MAGENTA]
    else
        return HUE_LIST[:RED]
    end
end
```

**Actual Results**

```
def hue_name_from_hue_value(hue_value)
    color_angle = hue_value * 360

    if 30 >= color_angle and color_angle < 90
        return HUE_LIST[:RED]
    elsif 90 >= color_angle and color_angle < 150
        return HUE_LIST[:YELLOW]
    elsif 150 >= color_angle and color_angle < 210
        return HUE_LIST[:GREEN]
    elsif 210 >= color_angle and color_angle < 270
        return HUE_LIST[:CYAN]
    elsif 270 >= color_angle and color_angle < 330
        return HUE_LIST[:BLUE]
    else
        return HUE_LIST[:MAGENTA]
    end
end
```

**Question**
Why is my conversion off by 60 degrees (is it off by 60 degrees)? 
I have included the source code of my implementation of the RGB to HSL algorithm for reference.

**EasyRGB.com Pseudocode**

```
var_R = ( R / 255 )                     //RGB from 0 to 255
var_G = ( G / 255 )
var_B = ( B / 255 )

var_Min = min( var_R, var_G, var_B )    //Min. value of RGB
var_Max = max( var_R, var_G, var_B )    //Max. value of RGB
del_Max = var_Max - var_Min             //Delta RGB value

L = ( var_Max + var_Min ) / 2

if ( del_Max == 0 )                     //This is a gray, no chroma...
{
   H = 0                                //HSL results from 0 to 1
   S = 0
}
else                                    //Chromatic data...
{
   if ( L < 0.5 ) S = del_Max / ( var_Max + var_Min )
   else           S = del_Max / ( 2 - var_Max - var_Min )

   del_R = ( ( ( var_Max - var_R ) / 6 ) + ( del_Max / 2 ) ) / del_Max
   del_G = ( ( ( var_Max - var_G ) / 6 ) + ( del_Max / 2 ) ) / del_Max
   del_B = ( ( ( var_Max - var_B ) / 6 ) + ( del_Max / 2 ) ) / del_Max

   if      ( var_R == var_Max ) H = del_B - del_G
   else if ( var_G == var_Max ) H = ( 1 / 3 ) + del_R - del_B
   else if ( var_B == var_Max ) H = ( 2 / 3 ) + del_G - del_R

   if ( H < 0 ) H += 1
   if ( H > 1 ) H -= 1
}
```

**My implementation of the Pseudocode in Ruby**

```
def rgb_to_hsl(red, green, blue)
    hsl_values = {:hue => 0, :saturation => 0, :lightness => 0}

    if
        (red.is_a?(Integer) && green.is_a?(Integer) && blue.is_a?(Integer)) == false
        return hsl_values
    end

    red /= 255.to_f
    green /= 255.to_f
    blue /= 255.to_f

    hue = 0.to_f
    saturation = 0.to_f
    lightness = 0.to_f

    minimum = [red, green, blue].min
    maximum = [red, green, blue].max
    delta_max = maximum - minimum

    lightness = (maximum + minimum) / 2

    if delta_max == 0 #gray
        hue = 0
        saturation = 0
    else
        if lightness < 0.5
            saturation = delta_max / (maximum + minimum)
        else
            saturation = delta_max / (2 - maximum - minimum)
        end

        delta_red = (((maximum - red) / 6) + (maximum / 2)) / delta_max
        delta_green = (((maximum - green) / 6) + (maximum / 2)) / delta_max
        delta_blue = (((maximum - blue) / 6) + (maximum / 2)) / delta_max

        if red == maximum
            hue = delta_blue - delta_green
        elsif green == maximum
            hue = (1 / 3) + delta_red - delta_blue
        elsif blue == maximum
            hue = (2 / 3) + delta_green - delta_red
        end

        if hue < 0
            hue += 1
        end

        if hue > 1
            hue -= 1
        end
    end

    hsl_values[:hue] = hue
    hsl_values[:saturation] = saturation
    hsl_values[:lightness] = lightness
    return hsl_values
end
```

Comment: You could simplify the code a lot by tackling those `delta_xyz` variables. The only thing they're used for is to subtract one from the other, so there's no point having `2/3 * maximum / delta_max` in both of them. Once that's simplified, it should be easier to see what the ranges of output can be for each case.

Comment: Moving my answer as comment as it did not resolve the issue:
`1/3` is always zero. Please note you are performing integer division here. Same holds for `2/3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem after a little bit of research on the Ruby language.

First, I was getting a rounding error because some of my calculations weren't doing floating point math. I fixed these by appending the `to_f` method to integers where needed.

Second, there was a mistake in my logic for determining the hue. I found the `between?(a, b)` method and substituted it in for the equalities that I programmed. This fixed the problem.

The rewritten code is below.

```
def hue_name_from_hue_value(hue_value)
    color_angle = hue_value * 360

    if color_angle.between?(31, 90)
        return HUE_LIST[:YELLOW]
    elsif color_angle.between?(91,150)
        return HUE_LIST[:GREEN]
    elsif color_angle.between?(151,210)
        return HUE_LIST[:CYAN]
    elsif color_angle.between?(211,270)
        return HUE_LIST[:BLUE]
    elsif color_angle.between?(271,330)
        return HUE_LIST[:MAGENTA]
    else
        return HUE_LIST[:RED]
    end
end
```