# How to animate text fill with gradient colors?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS animations and trying to figure this out. I'm trying to set an animated text fill gradient between three specified colors. However, my text seems to cycle through colors that aren't the ones specified. Why is that?

```
.gradient-text {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(125deg, #810ea8, #ab5ec5, #ead7f1);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-animation: hue 15s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

I only want to make the colors cycle between #810ea8, #ab5ec5, and #ead7f1. How would I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you want only exactly those three colors to show, no gradual fading from one to another for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to animate your `background-position` from 0% to 100% of the background size. Make the background size much bigger than the element you're animating so you get a gradual change of colour. I've animated the background to clearly show what's going on but you can apply it to your text.

If you go through all 360 degrees in the [hue property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue), then you'll cycle through all colours as per the colour wheel below (pinched from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27451695/12571484) on Stackoverflow)

[image]

Marked up code below.

```css
.gradient-text {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #810ea8 0%, #ab5ec5 50%, #ead7f1 100%);
  background-size: 1000% 100%;
  animation: changecolor 10s infinite linear;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: max-content;
}
@keyframes changecolor {
  0%, 100% {
    background-position: 0%;  
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-text">Here is some gradient text</div>
```